# Expandable List View - Referencing and using buttons in a child row

Tags: android

I am building an application that will use an expandable list view to display a list of preferences.  I have built the group and child lists with no problem using separate xml layouts for the group rows and child rows (as found in most examples here and Android docs).  My child layout includes two buttons which would be used to indicate if a user wants to include or exclude that item in their preferences.

What I am struggling with, how do I obtain the correct handle for each button for each child and then create an onClick listener for each button so that I can:

**a)** change the appearance of each button when clicked, and **b)** use the click action or state later on to store a boolean type response indicating whether the user wants/dont wants that preference?

I have found samples where you can build an action based on the user clicking the child itself, but I need to actually build the action based on the user clicking on one of the buttons in the child.

Unfortunately, this forum does not allow me to post an image to show what I am talking about, so hopefully my question is clear.

Any thoughts on how I might go about getting button functionality?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by the child view. But it sounds to me like you should just use a toggle button with an xml selector

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are referring to?  When I say child view, I am referring to the 2nd level of the expandable list view, ie the child of the group.  The 2nd level is a list of items that are all driven off an xml layout for that row, but the real question is how to reference and use buttons imbedded in each 2nd level row.